# CarouselView Snap Points Alignment not working in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using CarouselView to display data, do I use **SnapPointsAlignment** property for it:

```
<CarouselView x:Name="_data" PeekAreaInsets="40" ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
    <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" SnapPointsType="Mandatory" SnapPointsAlignment="Start" />
    </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        .....
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>    
</CarouselView>
```

I made AutoPlay for it:

```
...
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6), (Func<bool>)(() =>
{
    _data.Position = (_data.Position + 2) % _listProd.Count;
    return true;
}));
```

In the example I use **SnapPointsAlignment="Start"**. **However when I display my first data it stays in the middle**. I searched in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/scrolling#start-1). However, still not found the solution described

[image]

**What I look forward to**

[image]

**Note that I don't want to use CollectionView, because I have a hard time looping it**

I am using XF 5.0.0.2291. Looking forward to everyone's help. Thank you

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I uploaded the demo to Github: https://github.com/chimditruvn/App2. You can test it on android + iOS. Thank you very much

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Looking forward to your response. Best regards

Comment: Really bothered you. I've been waiting for more than 2 days, but haven't heard from you yet. Is my problem possible?

Comment: Are you sure your code is uploaded correctly? I deployed the project to my phone and the app crashed.

Comment: Please try to download it again: https://github.com/chimditruvn/App2. I downloaded and tested it without crashing. Tks!

Comment: Have you tried it yet? I've been waiting quite a while but didn't see your response. Thank!

Comment: I tested with Google Pixel (android 10),the app crashed as soon as it launched. But after I tested with an android simulator(android 12),  the problem disappeared.  And every time the image scrolls and stops, it's in the start position.

Comment: Do you test on iOS? On android I'm trying on SS Galaxy S8

Comment: I did a test on iOS (ios 15.5),it also works properly.