# How to Sticky StackLayout in Scrollview Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to **Sticky x:Name="_menucate"** when scrolling like the example on Twitter

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
<ScrollView x:Name="scrollmain" Scrolled="scrollmain_Scrolled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Frame/>
            <Frame/>
            <Frame/>
            <Frame/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <ScrollView x:Name="_menucate" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                <Grid Margin="0" Padding="5,0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" ColumnSpacing="10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Label Text="Menu 1" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Label Text="Menu 2" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollView>
           <StackLayout>
              <Frame/>
              <Frame/>
           </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Page1.xaml.cs**

```
public Page1()
{
     scrollmain.PropertyChanged += Scrollmain_PropertyChanged;
     _menucate.SizeChanged += _menucate_SizeChanged;
}
double _titleTextTop;
private void _menucate_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _menucate.SizeChanged -= _menucate_SizeChanged;
    _titleTextTop = _menucate.Y;
}
private void Scrollmain_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName.Equals(Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView.ScrollYProperty.PropertyName))
    {
        var scrolled = ((Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView)sender).ScrollY;

        if (scrolled < _titleTextTop)
            _menucate.TranslationY = (0 - scrolled);
        else
            _menucate.TranslationY = (0 - _titleTextTop);
    }
}

private void scrollmain_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
{
    //Load more other
}
```

I have tried to do as the code above. However it doesn't work. Maybe I misunderstood the problem. Looking forward to everyone's help. Thank you

**Update 1 .xaml**

I removed 1 ScrollView inside ScrollView x:Name="scrollmain"

```
<ScrollView x:Name="scrollmain" Scrolled="scrollmain_Scrolled">
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Frame/>
            ...... //more
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid x:Name="_menucate" Margin="0" Padding="5,0" ColumnSpacing="10">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Label Text="Menu 1" />
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Label Text="Menu 2" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <StackLayout>
               .... //More
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Update 2**

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">            
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>            
    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <Label Text="FIXED HEADER DEMO" Margin="12" FontSize="14" />
        <ScrollView x:Name="TheScroll">
            <StackLayout>
                <StackLayout x:Name="BearImage">
                    <Image Source="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg"
                   Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                    <Image Source="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg"
                   Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                    <Image Source="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg"
                   Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                    <Image Source="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg"
                   Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                    <Image Source="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg"
                   Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                    <Image Source="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg"
                   Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                </StackLayout>
                
                <Label LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                   Margin="12,5,12,5"
                   Grid.Row="1">
                    <Label.FormattedText>
                        <FormattedString>
                            <Span Text="Never heard before, but a bear was found in the wild!" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="18" />
                            <Span Text="&#10;&#10;Bears are mammals of the family Ursidae. Bears are classified as caniforms, or doglike carnivorans, with the pinnipeds being their closest living relatives. Although only eight species of bears are extant, they are widespread, appearing in a wide variety of habitats throughout the Northern Hemisphere and partially in the Southern Hemisphere. Bears are found on the continents of North America, Central America, South America, Europe, and Asia.
&#10;&#10;Common characteristics of modern bears include large bodies with stocky legs, long snouts, shaggy hair, plantigrade paws with five nonretractile claws, and short tails. While the polar bear is mostly carnivorous and the giant panda feeds almost entirely on bamboo, the remaining six species are omnivorous, with varied diets.
&#10;&#10;With the exceptions of courting individuals and mothers with their young, bears are typically solitary animals. They are generally diurnal, but may be active during the night (nocturnal) or twilight (crepuscular), particularly around humans. Bears are aided by an excellent sense of smell, and despite their heavy build and awkward gait, they can run quickly and are adept climbers and swimmers. In autumn, some bear species forage large amounts of fermented fruits, which affects their behaviour.[1] Bears use shelters, such as caves and burrows, as their dens; most species occupy their dens during the winter for a long period (up to 100 days) of sleep similar to hibernation.[2]
                              FontSize="14" />
                        </FormattedString>
                    </Label.FormattedText>
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>


        <ScrollView x:Name="_menucate" Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="40" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  Spacing="-6" Padding="1">
                <Button Text="Menu1" />
                <Button Text="Menu2" />
                <Button Text="Menu3" />
                <Button Text="Menu4" />
                <Button Text="Menu5" />
                <Button Text="Menu6" />
                <Button Text="Menu7" />
                <Button Text="Menu8" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**.xaml.cs**

```
double _titleTextTop;

public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TheScroll.PropertyChanged += OnScrollViewPropertyChanged;
    BearImage.SizeChanged += OnBearImageSizeChanged;
    _menucate.SizeChanged += OnTitleTextSizeChanged;
}

private void OnTitleTextSizeChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    _menucate.SizeChanged -= OnTitleTextSizeChanged;

    //As soon as the news header has been repositioned, we can grab the actual screen top position
    _titleTextTop = _menucate.Y;

    //Remark: GetScreenCoordinates will get the actual position on screen instead of the actual position inside the parent
    //_titleTextTop = GetScreenCoordinates(TitleText).Y;
}

private void OnBearImageSizeChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    BearImage.SizeChanged -= OnBearImageSizeChanged;

    //When the bear image has been loaded, reposition the news header to the bottom of this image
    _menucate.Margin = new Thickness(0, BearImage.Height - 40, 0, 0);
}

private void OnScrollViewPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName.Equals(ScrollView.ScrollYProperty.PropertyName))
    {
        var scrolled = ((ScrollView)sender).ScrollY;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Y position: {scrolled.ToString()}");

        if (scrolled < _titleTextTop)
            _menucate.TranslationY = (0 - scrolled);
        else
            _menucate.TranslationY = (0 - _titleTextTop);
    }
}

public (double X, double Y) GetScreenCoordinates(VisualElement view)
{
    // A view's default X- and Y-coordinates are LOCAL with respect to the boundaries of its parent,
    // and NOT with respect to the screen. This method calculates the SCREEN coordinates of a view.
    // The coordinates returned refer to the top left corner of the view.

    // Initialize with the view's "local" coordinates with respect to its parent
    double screenCoordinateX = view.X;
    double screenCoordinateY = view.Y;

    // Get the view's parent (if it has one...)
    if (view.Parent.GetType() != typeof(App))
    {
        VisualElement parent = (VisualElement)view.Parent;


        // Loop through all parents
        while (parent != null)
        {
            // Add in the coordinates of the parent with respect to ITS parent
            screenCoordinateX += parent.X;
            screenCoordinateY += parent.Y;

            // If the parent of this parent isn't the app itself, get the parent's parent.
            if (parent.Parent.GetType() == typeof(App))
                parent = null;
            else
                parent = (VisualElement)parent.Parent;
        }
    }

    // Return the final coordinates...which are the global SCREEN coordinates of the view
    return (screenCoordinateX, screenCoordinateY);
}
```

It seems that when the data inside the `<StackLayout x:Name="BearImage">` exceeds the current screen, the `x:Name="_menucate"` is no longer visible. As in the example above I leave 5 images -> do not exceed the screen, then it displays `x:Name="_menucate"`, if the number of images is greater than 5 -> passes the current screen, then `x:Name="_menucate"` won't show up?

Comment: Having a scrollview nested inside another scrollview is not recommended. Do you really need the outer scrollview? If not, its easy; whatever you want to stick don't have inside the scrollview. So you have a fixed area at top, and a scrolling area below it.

Comment: Yes, because above my `ScrollView x:Name="_menucate"` contains a lot of data which makes it very tall. So I just nested `ScrollView x:Name="_menucate"` inside ScrollView `x:Name="scrollmain"`

Comment: I have updated the .xaml, removed 1 ScrollView inside ScrollView x:Name="scrollmain". Do you have any solution for it. Thank you

Comment: You can provide a minimal sample via GitHub so I can help you test it. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Thank you for responding. I uploaded it to Github: https://github.com/chimditruvn/StickyApp You can check it out. Thank you

Comment: Really bothered you. I've been waiting for more than 2 days, but haven't heard from you yet. Is my problem possible?

Comment: Looks like system blocked your message. I have posted my answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to update the `_menucate`'s  `TranslationY` while scrolling the page!

Here's the code sample for your reference:

**Code in Xaml:**

```
     <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
            <Grid.Margin>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="0,20,0,0" />
                </OnPlatform>
            </Grid.Margin>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Text="FIXED HEADER DEMO" Margin="12" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="14" />
            <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" Grid.Row="1">
                <ScrollView x:Name="TheScroll">
                    <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="ImageRow" Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image x:Name="BearImage" Source="XamarinLogo.png"
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           Grid.Row="0" />
                        <Label LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                           Margin="12,5,12,5"
                           Grid.Row="1">
                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                <FormattedString>
                                    <Span Text="Never heard before, but a bear was found in the wild!" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="18" />
                                    <Span Text="&#10;&#10;Bears are mammals of the family Ursidae. Bears are classified as caniforms, or doglike carnivorans, with the pinnipeds being their closest living relatives. Although only eight species of bears are extant, they are widespread, appearing in a wide variety of habitats throughout the Northern Hemisphere and partially in the Southern Hemisphere. Bears are found on the continents of North America, Central America, South America, Europe, and Asia.
&#10;&#10;Common characteristics of modern bears include large bodies with stocky legs, long snouts, shaggy hair, plantigrade paws with five nonretractile claws, and short tails. While the polar bear is mostly carnivorous and the giant panda feeds almost entirely on bamboo, the remaining six species are omnivorous, with varied diets.
&#10;&#10;With the exceptions of courting individuals and mothers with their young, bears are typically solitary animals. They are generally diurnal, but may be active during the night (nocturnal) or twilight (crepuscular), particularly around humans. Bears are aided by an excellent sense of smell, and despite their heavy build and awkward gait, they can run quickly and are adept climbers and swimmers. In autumn, some bear species forage large amounts of fermented fruits, which affects their behaviour.[1] Bears use shelters, such as caves and burrows, as their dens; most species occupy their dens during the winter for a long period (up to 100 days) of sleep similar to hibernation.[2]
&#10;&#10;Bears have been hunted since prehistoric times for their meat and fur. With their tremendous physical presence and charisma, they play a prominent role in the arts, mythology, and other cultural aspects of various human societies. In modern times, the bears' existence has been pressured through the encroachment on their habitats and the illegal trade of bears and bear parts, including the Asian bile bear market. The IUCN lists six bear species as vulnerable or endangered, and even least concern species, such as the brown bear, are at risk of extirpation in certain countries. The poaching and international trade of these most threatened populations are prohibited, but still ongoing."
                                      FontSize="14" />
                                </FormattedString>
                            </Label.FormattedText>
                        </Label>
                    </Grid>
                </ScrollView>


                <ScrollView x:Name="_menucate" Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="40" VerticalOptions="Start">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  Spacing="-6" Padding="1">
                        <Button Text="Menu1" />
                        <Button Text="Menu2" />
                        <Button Text="Menu3" />
                        <Button Text="Menu4" />
                        <Button Text="Menu5" />
                        <Button Text="Menu6" />
                        <Button Text="Menu7" />
                        <Button Text="Menu8" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ScrollView>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

**Code behind:**

```
  public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        double _titleTextTop;

        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TheScroll.PropertyChanged += OnScrollViewPropertyChanged;
            BearImage.SizeChanged += OnBearImageSizeChanged;
            _menucate.SizeChanged += OnTitleTextSizeChanged;
        }

        private void OnTitleTextSizeChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            _menucate.SizeChanged -= OnTitleTextSizeChanged;

            //As soon as the news header has been repositioned, we can grab the actual screen top position
            _titleTextTop = _menucate.Y;

            //Remark: GetScreenCoordinates will get the actual position on screen instead of the actual position inside the parent
            //_titleTextTop = GetScreenCoordinates(TitleText).Y;
        }

        private void OnBearImageSizeChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            BearImage.SizeChanged -= OnBearImageSizeChanged;

            //When the bear image has been loaded, reposition the news header to the bottom of this image
            _menucate.Margin = new Thickness(0, BearImage.Height - 40, 0, 0);
        }

        private void OnScrollViewPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName.Equals(ScrollView.ScrollYProperty.PropertyName))
            {
                var scrolled = ((ScrollView)sender).ScrollY;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Y position: {scrolled.ToString()}");

                if (scrolled < _titleTextTop)
                    //you can set the position by setting below
                    _menucate.TranslationY = (0 - scrolled);
                else
                    _menucate.TranslationY = (0 - _titleTextTop);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I tried your code send, however the _menucate part is always on top? (I have attached in update). Can you try for the code in the github I submitted?

Comment: Looking forward to more help from you. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your response! 1.Don't wrap scrollview with stacklayout 2.You can set the position of `_menucate part` by setting ` _menucate.TranslationY = (0 - scrolled);` in `OnScrollViewPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Despite its many shortcomings, I will nevertheless mark it as useful. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Alexandar May - MSFT , Sorry to bother you. I have a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72990197/carouselview-snap-points-alignment-not-working-in-xamarin?noredirect=1#comment129136655_72990197 but have not received a response. Can you watch it? Thank you

Comment: I have helped you contact with this question. You will probably get a response today.No worries.