# CollectionView does not automatically Srcoll in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using CollectionView to display data. I want **CollectionView autoplay**. However it doesn't work, even though I have it set to run automatically from time to time.. Don't know what I did wrong.

**.xaml**

```
<StackLayout HeightRequest="100">
    <CollectionView x:Name="_data" HeightRequest="150" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" SnapPointsType="Mandatory" SnapPointsAlignment="Start" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Image HorizontalOptions="Fill" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding Image}" WidthRequest="200"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

**.xaml.cs**

```
public Test2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadData();

}
protected async void LoadData()
{
    var monkeyJson = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(monkeyUrl);
    var monkeys = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Monkey[]>(monkeyJson);


    foreach (var monkey in monkeys)
    {
        Monkeys.Add(monkey);
    }

    _listProd = Monkeys.ToList();

    _data.ItemsSource = _listProd;

    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), (Func<bool>)(() =>
    {
        _data.ScrollTo(_listProd.Count + 2, -1, ScrollToPosition.Start, true);
        return true;
    }));
}
```

**Note that I used CarouselView. However this time I want to use CollectionView**

I searched for keywords related to CollectionView. However, there were no positive results. Looking forward to everyone's help. Thank you.

**Update**

```
...
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), (Func<bool>)(() =>
    {
        _data.ScrollTo(_listProd.Count + 2, -1, ScrollToPosition.Start, true);
        return true;
    }));
});
```

Comment: you need to be sure you're executing on MainThread

Comment: I added: MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(())... or Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(())... but it still doesn't work. I have updated the above. Looking forward to more clarity from you. Thank you!

Comment: Bases on your code ,I did a test,but the `CollectionView`  could scroll  to the last item automatically . Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: This question to solve for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72990197/carouselview-snap-points-alignment-not-working-in-xamarin. And you still haven't responded for me it doesn't work on XF iOS :(

Comment: Only the ScrollTo line needs to be on MainThread